# change Server time to our local machine`s time in Java

Tags: java, timezone

I am developing a web application (in jsp) which is used worldwide.
Now I need to change date and time to local machine specific(in java).

For example my web server is in USA and a client from India opens the application then the application should change all the date and time in the IST (Indian Standered Time) format.

Actually, what I am looking for is like this --

```
import java.text.DateFormat; 
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.TimeZone; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TZConvert { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
       Date date1 = format.parse("14-Feb-2014  14:40:00");

       DateFormat localDf = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL);  

       System.out.println("local : " + localDf.format(date1)); 

    }  
}
```

I want value of "date1" should change in different timezone. If a person from EST timezone he should see this date and time (14-Feb-2014 14:40:00) and if a person open the application he should see "15-Feb-2014 01:10:00".

Answer (score 0):

Ok so that is kinda broad problem everybody has. Right?

What you need to do is to define parts of i18n stuff (meaning localizations) in your client code via `Javascript` and the rest on your server. For client side, Javascript is a powerful language that can receive stuff from your client's browser or location API in HTML5 and present them in their own manner. Native Javascript API is not so strong to define such problems therefore a lot of libraries are famous that will help you achieve that. Check [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) for example. On the server side, you will also need to take care of stuff such as to receive local time your client has logged in or whatever. For that, there are not so many libraries who will do the job but look at [JODA open source library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).

Then after playing with them, come back here with more library-specific problem. I think that is a nice start.

Good luck!